# How to use special characters in recipients name when using PHP's mail function

Tags: php, email, character-encoding

How can I send an email formatted as "`Name <user@example.com>`" to:

```
ŠŒŽœžŸ¥µÀÁÃÄÅÆÇÉÊËÍÎÏÐÒÓÕÖØÙÜÝßàáâåæçèéëìíîïðñóôõöøùûýÿ <user@example.com>
```

Obviously, many of these characters will never show up in a name, but in case they do, I would prefer that they do not prevent an email from being successfully sent.

Currently, this fails as noted in Apache's error.log with

> Ignoring invalid 'To:' recipient address
>   '¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ
>   ' Transaction aborted: no recipients specified

If possible, I would like to keep the special characters 'as they are.'
Otherwise, can I use some sort of transliteration function to clean-up the name?

Example of usage:

```
 <?php
 $to = "ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ <CHANGED@gmail.com>";
 $subject = "Test Subject";
 $body = "Test Body";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`mb_encode_mimeheader`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-encode-mimeheader.php) should do it, just as shown in the example:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

$name  = '山本';
$email = 'yamamoto@example.com';
$addr  = mb_encode_mimeheader($name, 'UTF-8', 'Q') . " <$email>";
```

For better compatibility you should set the header `Mime-Version: 1.0` so all mail clients understand you're using MIME encoding.

The final email headers should look like this:

```
To: =?UTF-8?Q?=E5=B0=81=E3=83=90=E3=83=BC?= <yamamoto@example.com>
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?=E3=81=93=E3=82=93=E3=81=AB=E3=81=A1=E3=81=AF?=
Mime-Version: 1.0
```

Renders as:

```
To: 山本 <yamamoto@example.com>
Subject: こんにちは
```

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13569317/476

Comment: Perhaps also add a pointer to RFC2048 which defines this behavior. MIME is essential if you want to handle email.

Comment: Thank you deceze, this works perfectly. @tripleee Thank you for the RFC reference.  I didn't realize this applied to all parts of an email.

Comment: Is it also possible to encode special charaters **and** spaces? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963712/how-to-correctly-encode-strings-for-usage-in-mail-headers-in-php) Unfortunately `mb_encode_mimeheader` does not help in that case.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @deceze's answer, when using Quoted Printable mode it may be necessary to escape any quotes in the name on any to/from/reply-to/etc headers:

```
$addr = '"'.str_replace('"', '\"', mb_encode_mimeheader($name, 'UTF-8', 'Q'))."\" <$email>";
```

Perhaps this isn't necessary for all MTAs, but at least for me a name with a "  lead the MTA to interpret the header as multiple local addresses.

Answer (score 1):

RFC-821 (2821) tells us, that **all and any** 8bit-data in headers field must be encoded. Base64 or QuotedPrintable, as you want and can. Most e-mail readers automatically decode encoded strings