# What HTML entity to use in the email subject line for a heart?

Tags: html, encoding, entity

This question may sound like stupid but I tried all possible HTML entities and the subject line for the email I send is still not showing the heart on Apple devices (iPhone, iPad, etc).

It may be just the software I use for testing (MaxBulk Mailer, ExactTarget).

I also tried different charset (UTF-8, ascii, etc).

Does anybody know how to make a heart appear as a heart into the subject line of an email for Apple devices?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if they stripped it out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The subject line is part of the email headers. The email headers may only contain ASCII characters. The subject line is not being interpreted as HTML or anything else, it's plain text. You need to embed the character as Unicode character, but you cannot do this since the headers must be in ASCII. To embed any non-ASCII characters in a header, you need to use a [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) [Encoded-Word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word).

See [`mb_encode_mimeheader`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-encode-mimeheader.php), read its examples.

The resulting header will need to look something like this:

```
Subject: =?utf-8?B?4p2k?=
```

Which decodes to this in the mail client:

> ❤

Comment: Thanks man, now we have a heart on iPhone but a square on BlackBerry. Such a frustrating experience with all these devices :(

Comment: A square means it doesn't have a *font* which can display the character.

Comment: if is not too much to ask, how did you do to get that code u shared? =?utf-8?B?4p2k?=

Comment: Well, originally I just sent myself an email... :P But here's a reproduction in actual code: http://3v4l.org/J4Z5S

Answer (score 3):

With regards to your question [here](http://www.emailmarketingtipps.de/2012/02/21/specials-characters-and-symbols-in-email-subject-lines-does-it-work/#comment-2619): you may have picked the wrong heart. Try ♥ instead of ❤. The first one should render on a BlackBerry (and Android 2.2), too, as [this test shows](http://www.emailmarketingtipps.de/2012/11/19/symbols-tested-in-subject-lines-on-iphone-hotmail/). The latter one, however, doesn't.