# Encoding Subject Line for Email

Tags: objective-c, email, utf-8

The body of an email can be encoded according to encoding specified in a header. This cannot be done for the Subject, which must use a different format. How can this be done in Objective C. A working example of what I'm trying to do is shown at [this website](http://www.sendblaster.com/en/utf8-email-subject-encoder).

The output of the method should return what is being returned on this website on the second line: "Encoded Result:".

This is described in [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047). I'll wade through this, if necessary, but surely this has already been done.

Comment: Appears to hold the answer: [What HTML entity to use in the email subject line for a heart?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13569067)

Comment: OK. I think I found a solution that works (code, above, is updated)

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSData *dataForSubject = [message.subject dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *base64Subject = [dataForSubject base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    NSString *stringToPass = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"=?utf-8?b?%@?=",base64Subject];
```